# Regular expression to get quantity and names of ingredients

Tags: php, regex

I have been asked to get the quantities and ingredient from ingredient list. I have successfully extracted quantity and ingredient from list but i am stuck where one half characters occurs such as ¼, ½, etc. They are not encoded in HTML and my regex fails there.

Here is the list of ingredients

```
$subject = array("1 teaspoon salt",
"¼ teaspoon black pepper",
"1 cup all-purpose flour",
"1 ½ - 2 cups shredded Parmesan cheese");
```

### Regex

```
 preg_replace ('/(([0-9][\s+]*[\-]*[0-9]*[\s+]*)(teaspoon|tablespoons|cup|cups)*)([a-z0-9\s]+)/','Quantity: $1 Name: $4',$food)
```

### Output

```
 Quantity: 1 teaspoon Name: salt
 ¼ teaspoon black pepper (failed)
 Quantity: 1 cup Name: all-purpose flour
 Quantity: 1 Name: ½ - Quantity: 2 cup Name: s shredded Parmesan cheese (failed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate the [Unicode code points](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html#fractions) into your regular expression.  At first blush, it looks like the appropriate codepoints are `[\x{00BC}-\x{00BE}\x{2153}-\x{215E}]`  You'll also have to use a `u` modifier, to enable unicode in preg.